# Converting nested JSON

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, pandas, nested

I have the following data:

```
josonloc = [{u'borough': u'MANHATTAN',
u'location': {u'latitude': u'40.8082795',
u'needs_recoding': False},
u'unique_key': u'3405059',
u'zip_code': u'10035'}]
```

But when I import the data , it is not displayed right

```
df = pd.read_joson(jsonloc)
```

[image: Screenshot]

I tried cleaning the data with:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
result = json_normalize(config, 'location',['latitude','longitude','needs_recoding'])
```

But that does not seem to work.  I get:

```
KeyError: 'needs_recoding'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) without parameters:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

jsonloc = [{u'borough': u'MANHATTAN',
u'location': {u'latitude': u'40.8082795',
u'needs_recoding': False},
u'unique_key': u'3405059',
u'zip_code': u'10035'}]

result = json_normalize(jsonloc)
print result
     borough location.latitude location.needs_recoding unique_key zip_code
0  MANHATTAN        40.8082795                   False    3405059    10035
```

If you want change columns names, use list comprehension with [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
cols = result.columns.str.split('.')
print cols
Index([                    [u'borough'],       [u'location', u'latitude'],
       [u'location', u'needs_recoding'],                  [u'unique_key'],
                          [u'zip_code']],
      dtype='object')

print [col[0] if len(col) == 1 else col[1] for col in result.columns.str.split('.')]
[u'borough', 'latitude', 'needs_recoding', u'unique_key', u'zip_code']

result.columns=[col[0] if len(col) == 1 else col[1] for col in result.columns.str.split('.')]
print result
     borough    latitude needs_recoding unique_key zip_code
0  MANHATTAN  40.8082795          False    3405059    10035
```